# Submit file with appengine python, after control with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I'm trying to have a simple check on an input file. sended through a form, using Javascript , with App Engine in Python runtime and using Jinja2. The form is the following:

```
<form action="{{ upload_url|safe }}" name="inputfile" id="inputfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Load a file:
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"><br>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Send" onclick="checkForm()">
</form></br>
```

The checkForm() function is the following:

```
function checkForm(){
var message ="";

if(!document.inputfile.file.value) message += "You must select a file\n";
if(document.inputfile.file.value && !(estensione(document.inputfile.file.value))) message += "The extension of the file MUST be .txt\n";

if(message != "" ) alert(message);
else document.inputfile.submit();   
}
```

There aren't problems with the alert message when I try to submit no file or a not txt file. But when it's all right the function doesn't submit the file.
If I use a submit input, instead of button, the file is sended without problem.
Somebody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think inputs name is caused this problem. I tried code without name attiribute and it worked.
Can you try code after remove name field?

`<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="checkForm()">`

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. Now I make the check in the main handler, but i can't understand why it doesn't work in this way!